# react-select prevent menu to open onInputChange

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I'm trying to use the `react-select` component as an input and a select component.

Doing so I would like to prevent the menu to open while the user is typing the input.

I just can't find a way to update this behavior by either a prop or updating the `onInputChange` method.

My problem if I decide to use a controlled state with the `menuIsOpen` prop is that I can't manage to reopen the Menu control is clicked.

Here is what I have so far, do you guys any idea of how this could be achieved ?

```
<StyledSelect
  components={{ IndicatorSeparator }}
  {..._.omit(this.props, [])}
  filterOption={() => true}
  inputValue={inputValue}
  onChange={value => {
    this.select.setState({ menuIsOpen: false });
    this.setState({ selectValue: value });
  }}
  onInputChange={(value, event) => {
    if (event && event.action === 'input-change') {
      this.setState({ inputValue: value });
    }
  }}
  openMenuOnClick={false}
/>
```

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XPRfy.png)

Comment: Just to clarify, when the user type the menu stays close but when you click on the arrow (or kg in your example) it opens ?

Comment: Yes that is exactly what I want.

Answer (score 3):

I think you are in the right direction using `onInputChange` and I would add a controlled `menuIsOpen` props like the following code:

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      menuIsOpen: false
    };
  }

  openMenu = () => {
    this.setState({ menuIsOpen: !this.state.menuIsOpen });
  };

  onInputChange = (props, { action }) => {
    if (action === "menu-close") this.setState({ menuIsOpen: false });
  };

  render() {

    const DropdownIndicator = props => {
      return (
        components.DropdownIndicator && (
          <div
            onClick={this.openMenu}
            style={{ display: "flex", alignItems: "center" }}
          >
            <span style={{ marginLeft: 12 }}>kg</span>
            <components.DropdownIndicator
              {...props}
              onClick={() => {
                console.log("ici");
              }}
            />
          </div>
        )
      );
    };

    return (
      <Select
        components={{ DropdownIndicator }}
        options={options}
        onChange={this.onChange}
        onInputChange={this.onInputChange}
        menuIsOpen={this.state.menuIsOpen}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

The idea with this code is to fire an `onClick` event on the `DropdownIndicator` custom component.

Here a [live example](https://codesandbox.io/s/r48lv4p11n).

Comment: Thank you! that is what I was looking for. I couldn't think of a way to pass a prop to the component but didn't think of declaring it in the render method.